# How can I install Uniscan on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: perl

When I try to run `uniscan.pl` with `perl ./uniscan.pl`, I get this message:

```
Can't locate Moose.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ./Uniscan
    /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .)
    at Uniscan/Crawler.pm line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Uniscan/Crawler.pm line 3.
Compilation failed in require at ./uniscan.pl line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./uniscan.pl line 25.
```

Answer (score 4):

This can help

```
apt-get install libmoose-perl
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I install libwww-perl and it work.

```
sudo apt-get install libwww-perl
```